# Data communication in a scalable microservice architecture

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, architecture, scalability, microservices

We are working on a project to gain some knowledge about microservices and automatically scalable architectures. In this project we are building a small game where a user can fly a plane and shoot down other players online, hosted on the Amazon Web Services. The duration of a game should be about 10 minutes, a million games should (theoretically) be able to be played at the same time and about a thousand players should be able to play in a single game. So the application must really be scalable.

We are now hitting a hard part in the architecture. We want the server to calculate the positions of the players. Meaning that server gets key input requests with which it recalculates positions. Problem is that, because the application is scalable and there isn't just one server doing all the calculations and holding all the data, the input events will probably end up in different locations. We expect that constantly writing all positions to a database and reading it back to the client is too slow nor scalable enough. Also we don't want dedicated servers for single games as that could just waist the computation power (and money)

We have searches for different implementations by other game architectures, like messaging, but to no avail, we could not find any method that seamed fitting. We would like to know if there is any kind of pattern that could make this kind of implementation work? All we really need is a sense of direction for some possible patterns.

Comment: http://microservices.io/ is generally a good source to answer such questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try ElasticCache http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/WhatIs.html

This makes it easy to share positions between nodes
They discuss using it for a score table but it might be possible to use it for positional data

Combine ElasticCache with autoscaling http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/WhatIsAutoScaling.html and you should be able to expand the environment with demand

Answer (score 1):

Your example sounds like a prime use case for a streaming platform such as Apache Kafka. It is a scalable cluster itself and acts as a large queue of events (your game inputs) that are stored and made available to stream consumers (all your game servers). This has a very high performance and should be able to handle millions of inputs per second with a low latency.

You should also make sure to split up your game world into broader "zones" as to make sure that not every server requires the data from all others always. I'm sure that no player has all other players on his screen at any point in time.

Look into the [Kafka examples](https://kafka.apache.org/uses)

And the [performance measurements](https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines) with comparison to traditional DBs.